# Get email address of logged in user using ldap/php

Tags: php, ldap

I'm using `AuthLDAPURL` in our htaccess file to authenticate a user.  Is there a way to grab the user's email address once they're logged in using PHP??

Comment: I think this answer apply to your problems : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2239069/3964083

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use [`AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapremoteuserattribute) for this.  As described in the documentation (emphasis mine):

> If this directive is set, the value of the REMOTE_USER environment
>   variable will be set to the value of the attribute specified. Make
>   sure that this attribute is included in the list of attributes in the
>   AuthLDAPUrl definition, otherwise this directive will have no effect.
>   This directive, if present, takes precedence over
>   AuthLDAPRemoteUserIsDN. ***This directive is useful should you want
>   people to log into a website using an email address, but a backend
>   application expects the username as a userid***.

That's the opposite of what you describe but you can try specifying the e-mail address field to be returned.

Otherwise, after Apache has handed over to PHP, you could use the [PHP LDAP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) to connect to the server and query for the email based on the supplied `REMOTE_USER` variable.  This is simple enough with Active Directory, something like this (it'll differ depending on your LDAP provider):

```
$ldap = ldap_connect('ldap://yourserver'); // use 'ldaps' if you can!
ldap_bind($ldap, 'username', 'password');
$attributes = array('mail');
$search = ldap_search($ldap, 'base_dn', 'search_filter', $attributes);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $search);
```

`$data` should be an array with the e-mail address.