# Docker on Apache, how to pass a variable to my PHP web app?

Tags: php, apache, docker, ldap

I have a PHP WebApp, built in a Docker Container and hosted on Apache Web Server.

This App is only used internally on intranet, and I'm trying to figure out a way to allow logins based on the Windows Username (Single sign on), but for Apache there are only a few solutions that are outdated.

So what I'm trying to do, I implemented in Docker a Login with LDAP, using this module:

RUN a2enmod authnz_ldap

So when the user tries to access the Web App, a popup will display asking to login.

This all works correctly, my next step, is to pass the Username the User inputs in that popup to my Web Application.

So then, my Web Application will use that username to manage the permissions, showing and hiding parts of the Web App.

So how do I pass that username to my Application? I'm pretty new with docker so I have no clue on how I could achieve this, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly the Apache serving your app is inside the Docker container. Then Docker is out of the equation and your question is reduced to [How do I retrieve the user information of a user authenticated with Apache's mod_ldap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239069/how-do-i-retrieve-the-user-information-of-a-user-authenticated-with-apaches-mod).